# What does installing Ubuntu "alongside" Windows entail?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, wubi

I recently posted a question about an error I was receiving trying to access Ubuntu from the boot menu. I am using Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.x (I THINK because I haven't accessed it in over a year due to being unable to run an important program for one of my classes on Ubuntu).

On another laptop, I partitioned the hard drive and installed Windows and Ubuntu on the partitions. On this laptop, I simply installed Ubuntu from Windows, picking the option **alongside Windows**, and didn't partition my hard drive manually. I was under the impression that "alongside" entailed Ubuntu partitioning my hard drive, and that if I were to return my Windows partition to factory settings it would not affect the Ubuntu partition. However, given my current problem, I am wondering if I was mistaken in this assumption?

When installing Ubuntu from Windows, selecting **alongside Windows** as the option from the Ubuntu installer, does that simply install Ubuntu within the Windows partition and thus returning it to factory settings would wipe out anything I had on the Ubuntu OS as well?

Ubuntu is still in the boot menu as an option, but when I try to access it it says the drive is "corrupt" and wubi is mentioned in the error.

I additionally tried to download a program ran from Windows to investigate partitions and there were no sign of my Ubuntu partition viewable from Windows. Is it possible Windows just can't see it?

Any insights, corrections or answers are appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick question.. Are you be able to see any folders by the name `Ubuntu` under `C:\` (or the drive where windows is installed) partition...??

Comment: I cannot see those folders and it's not in my Uninstall program list either. Can you verify if installing Ubuntu "alongside" Windows does indeed just install it within the Windows partition? So reverting it back to factory settings must've deleted EVERYTHING I had on Ubuntu or is it possible some of my files are salvageable?

Comment: From what I understood is that you have installed Ubuntu inside windows (to the partition where windows is installed) assuming that it would create a partition separate. Well Ubuntu can be installed in two ways that is `1. inside windows partition` and `2. on a non-windows partition`. Nevertheless, if you did a factory reset on your workstation, it will surely reset to its original state. In that case, it will turn back all the settings to its original state (since it restores from a recovery image that has already been made). This is how it work, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you Azker. What gave me hope was the fact Ubuntu is still available as an option in the boot menu? If it completely reset everything back to factory settings wouldn't that not be available as an option? I can see it there, but it says that it's corrupt when I try to access it.

Comment: Okay! Simplest way to identify is that.. Just right click **My computer** > select **Manage** & then select **Disk Management**. Under disk management observe your disk partitions. Sometimes you may find partitions that cannot be read by windows.

Comment: *Sigh* Nothing except Windows, Recovery and an unnamed OEM partition 100mb. I am a CS student and I did all my programming practice with a program on Ubuntu and now that I'm back doing programming courses again I was hoping I didn't lose all my saved programs. I guess this means I did. Thanks so much for all your help, at least I know now it's all gone.

Answer (score 1):

This is called WUBI. Wubi creates a virtual Ubuntu inside Windows. Imagine it as a virtual machine you need to reboot into. You can still boot to both from the Windows Boot Manager, but there is no second partition. About the corruption, run CHKDSK from Windows, then, go into your **Programs and Features > Add Remove Programs** and uninstall Ubuntu. Run another CHKDSK. Finally, reinstall Ubuntu through WUBI

Wubi does not work (is unsupported) on systems later than Ubuntu 14.04.

If Ubuntu is not on your install list, there is a HUGE problem. Disregard all above instructions and:

1. (From Windows) Open a command line as Administrator
2. (From Windows) Run command `bcdedit`. Locate the Ubuntu entry. Find the identifier and take note of it.
3. (From Windows) Run command `bcdedit /delete <id from step 2>`
4. Download Ubuntu 12.04. Burn the ISO. Pop it in, click WUBI, go through everything.